# How many alchemical items can I create per day with Alchemist Dedication?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, multi-classing, alchemist

[Alchemist Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=665) says you get 2<sup>*</sup> free infused reagents per day. This part is clear :

> You gain the alchemist’s infused reagents class feature, gaining a number of reagents each day equal to your level. You also gain the Alchemical Crafting feat and four additional formulas for 1st-level alchemical items, as well as the ability to create free items during your daily preparations. Your **advanced alchemy** level is 1 and doesn’t increase on its own.

What is unclear, is how many actual items you can turn this into. You *seem* to get Advanced Alchemy, at least you have a level for it. The Advanced Alchemy feature of full Alchemists states:

> For each batch of infused reagents you spend, choose an alchemical item of your advanced alchemy level or lower that's in your formula book, and **make a batch of two** of that item.

So how many items can I make?

---

*) On 2nd level, when you can take this feat

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Alchemist Dedication grants you 2 infused reagents per day, equal to your level. It also gives you an advanced alchemy level of 1 that does not increase on its own.

The Advanced Alchemy ability allows you to create 2 alchemical items of your advanced alchemy level or lower for each batch of infused reagents spent. With the 2 infused reagents granted by Alchemist Dedication, you can divide those into 2 batches of 1 infused reagent each.

For each batch of 1 infused reagent, Advanced Alchemy lets you create 2 alchemical items. Since you have 2 batches from your 2 infused reagents, you can create 2 x 2 = 4 total alchemical items per day with the Alchemist Dedication feat.

Comment: Would 2 reagents not allow you to create 4 items, 2 per batch of infused reagents?

Comment: I edited the reply, ty, twas my bad